# Dataframe transformation of a excel file representing a tree view scheme in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, treeview

I have an excel file representing a tree view [image]:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [921,922,923,9211,9212,9213,9221,55,56,9231,9232], 
                   "broader": [920,920,920,921,921,9211,922,9221,9221,923,923],
                   "narrower": [[922, 923],[921, 923],[921, 922],[9212],[9211],[0],[0],[56],[55],[9232],[9231]],
                     "related": [[9211, 9212],[9221],[0],[9213],[0],[0],[55, 56],[0],[0],[0],[0]]
})
```

where the "id"'s are the nodes, "broader" the parent, "narrower" the nodes on the same level and "related" the children.

I would like to make an excel sheet where each line is a tree branch in order to know how many entries i have got depending on the level, i.e.:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"base": [920,920,'...'], 
                   "level 1": [921,921,'...'],
                   "level2": [9211,9212,'...'],
                     "level3": [9213,0,'...']
})
```

Does anyone have an idea about the way to do it?

Comment: Have you tried using [MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html)?

Comment: I do not know MultiIndex.. I will have a look!

Comment: It can be very useful indeed, but the data should be paired first, shouldn't they? It is what i am trying to do, preparing the data to do what you suggest

Comment: Can you give a simpler and smaller example on what you're trying to do? The original post is phrased too confusingly to easily understand what you want to achieve. (The image doesn't seem to help the understanding, as it's unclear how it relates to the question.)

Comment: The first dataframe describes the tree in terms of (broader, narrower and related). i am trying to get another dataframe describing also the same tree, but where the columns are: base, level1, level2, level3. So that the base contains only one id, the level1 its children (few id's), .. In reality, id's are like characteristics (from general to particular) of buildings i study. What I would like to do is to be able of counting the number of building characteristics at each level and then make statistics. Is that a little bit more clear?

Comment: And the problem is that I do not manage a way (a method) to obtain this new dataframe..